# Fencing in old C++ compilers

Tags: c++, multithreading, atomic, c++98

I have a multithreaded application which I need to compile on gcc 4.4, I am not allowed to use the c++0x flag.

I want a variable to behave atomically but unfortunately w/o the C++0x flag I am unable to use `atomic<T>` in C++.

I tried `boost::atomic` but it gives me an error saying

> ISO C++ forbids declaration of "atomic" with no type

Is there any other way to achieve atomicity under these conditions, can I use fencing - if yes then is there a guide or commonly used commands to achieve fencing in old C++.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `std::mutex` already existed, in gcc 4.4 days. Failing that, you can always fallback to POSIX mutexes.

Comment: If you just need atomic behavior (as in never partially written/read, vs. volatile) and don't need universal CPU support - most Intel/AMD processors provide atomic behavior for word-aligned values of corresponding bitness.

Comment: I also need to make sure that the writes are flushed immediately and reads are not read from cache.

Comment: `volatile`? (Waiting for comments explaining why `volatile` is not the answer.)

Comment: Can you use GCC's atomic builtins? https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.3/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html  As for `volatile`, Microsoft compilers provide automatic acquire/release semantics for `volatile` objects, but this is not standard behavior.  See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12a04hfd.aspx

Comment: I took Sam's advice and used mutex for the variable.

Comment: Language-level mechanisms do not normally force access to main memory rather than cache.  To do that, particularly if you need consistency with off-chip hardware, you need operating-system specific operations to force a cache flush or map memory as unchacheable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As advised by  Sam Varshavchik in the comments above, using POSIX std::mutex we can protect the variable in multithreaded application.

std::mutex is an overkill but it's the best we have for gcc 4.4.

C++11 atomic does a better job at solving this issue but is available only on more recent compilers.